# Why StatusBar.translucent not working in expo app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

The header of my app is covered by the StatusBar on Android. Everything I do, I cannot make it to not be covered.

I tried:

```
<StatusBar translucent={false} />
```

and

```
StatusBar.setTranslucent(false)
```

But it doesn't have any effect.

More info:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html

Answer (score 1):

In your app.json or expo.json you can add these properties.

```
"androidStatusBarColor": "#00796a",
 "androidStatusBar": {
      "barStyle": "light-content",
      "backgroundColor": "#00796a"
 },
```

Comment: Are you? It seems that it will only change the color of the StatusBar, but the statusbar will still hide content of my app

Comment: @Aminadav, I don't understand what you are saying. the bar color changed as expected? is the content light or dark?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this issue for two hours. So I think this may help others.

@dondragon2's answer is correct to me. the point is when you set a color on statusbar, translucent turns off. I was struggling with this because I didn't know what exactly is happening and this had several side effects on my app. So I think this details may help others.

**The issue:**

Expo sets StatusBar translucent mode ON by default and any subsequent change via code has no effect.

**Solution**

Turn translucent mode off by [setting the StatusBar color](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v31.0.0/guides/configuring-statusbar) in app.json or expo.json in older versions. After that, you can change StatusBar configuration as mentioned in [RN documents](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html)

**Why**

My idea is Expo goal is to make development easy and more cross-platform. Translucent mode is more similar to IOS so let's make it zero config by setting it as default and even you don't need to set a color because we set it as a gray layer for you! So, Expo assumes Setting a color means StatusBar is not transcluent. Do you want an opaque color? Set a color in app.json and watch it across application without any code and also translucent will turn off automatically. BUT, I don't understand why we can't turn off transcluent via code and using RN API!